# Storing and querying 100m+ lines of data

Tags: database, bigdata

Im currently looking for an efficient way to store and search through over 100 million entries having around 5 data points for each entry. This is something I will be using myself locally, so any database and client can be used. What is a cost-effective approach to accomplishing this in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest MySQL as RDBMS. Add indexes for important columns so search is not linear but logarithmic. The traditional GUI for MySQL is its MySQL Workbench. Take care of codification, `utf8mb4` is very good.